# Blazor is not rendering update SfCircularGauge

Tags: c#, blazor, syncfusion

I have blazor page with a SfCircularGauge component bind to Field Temp.
Population of Temp is by a reactive subscriber.

The SfCircularGauge is not updating.
What have I been missing ?

```
@code {
    private readonly SensorObs _sensorObs = new();
    public int Temp { get; set; } = 20;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {        
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
            _sensorObs.SubscribeOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default).Where(x => x.WindSpeed > 5)
                .Subscribe(x =>
                {
                    Temp = x.Temp;
                    this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
                });

        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _sensorObs.Start();
    }
}
```

Razor : With the binding

```
<div id="ControlRegion">
<SfCircularGauge Theme="Theme.Fluent" EnablePointerDrag="true" >
   ....
            </CircularGaugeRanges>
            <CircularGaugePointers>
                <CircularGaugePointer Value="@Temp" Radius="60%" PointerWidth="7">
                    <CircularGaugeCap Radius="7" Color="#757575">
                        <CircularGaugeCapBorder Width="8"></CircularGaugeCapBorder>
                    </CircularGaugeCap>
                    <CircularGaugeNeedleTail Length="25%"></CircularGaugeNeedleTail>
                </CircularGaugePointer>
            </CircularGaugePointers>
        </CircularGaugeAxis>
    </CircularGaugeAxes>
</SfCircularGauge>
```

Solution :

```
private int _temp;

public int Temp
{
    get => _temp;
    set { _temp = value; this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged); }
}

private IDisposable? _disp;
protected override async  Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _disp = Obs.Where(x => x.WindSpeed > 5)
          .Subscribe(x =>
          {
              Temp = x.Temp;

          });
    await Task.Run(()=>Obs.Start());

}
```

Comment: Can you put the event handler on the component (instead of a lamba) and see if works?

Comment: I think if you remove the check for `SynchronizationContext.Current` it will work - AspNetCore doesn't have a `SynchronizationContext`

Comment: Although I am not familiar with your reactive code - so don't know what you can use instead of `SynchronizationContext.Current`

Comment: Split the handler code out as suggested by @MayurEkbote.  Check 1: Is the subscription being registered? and 2:  Is the handler is getting hit?

Comment: In the future, do not edit an answer into the question. You can post a self-answer.

Comment: @MisterMagoo : when this is Blazor-server then there _is_ a SyncContext.

Comment: @HH Neither the documentation, nor testing confirms that - `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null` as expected.

Comment: It's not Null on my PC. Sure you tested that in a Server app?   And StateHasChanged() does a specific test that it is running on the _right_ SynchronizationContext.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
@code {
private int _temp;

public int Temp
{
    get => _temp;
    set { _temp = value; this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged); }
}

public int Wind
{
    get => _wind;
    set { _wind = value; this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged); }
}

private IDisposable? _disp;
private IDisposable? _disp2;
private int _wind;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _disp = Obs.Where(x => x.WindSpeed > 5)
          .Subscribe(x =>
          {
              Temp = x.Temp;

          });

    _disp2 = Obs
        .Subscribe(x =>
        {
            Wind = x.WindSpeed;

        });
    await Task.Run(() => Obs.Start());

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).